# Select the Latest Message Between the Chat of two userid and username in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have Chat Data Table

| idx | sender_name | sender_id | receiver_name | receiver_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jack | jackID | amy | amyID |
| 2 | NULL | jackID | NULL | amyID |
| 3 | NULL | JackID | amy | amyID |
| 4 | jack | jackID | NULL | amyID |
| 5 | jack | jackID | NULL | amyID |
| 6 | amy | amyID | jack | jackID |
| 7 | null | amyID | jack | jackID |

A NULL sender or receiver indicates that the sender or receiver is anonymous.
For example, If Jack sends a chat anonymously to Amy, the data is saved as follows.

| idx | sender_name | sender_id | receiver_name | receiver_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NULL | jackID | amy | amyID |

And if Jack sends a chat to Amy in his own name, it will look something like this:

| idx | sender_name | sender_id | receiver_name | receiver_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jack | jackID | amy | amyID |

I want to select the last data from this table between receiver and sender with same name and id.
Like this:

| idx | sender_name | sender_id | receiver_name | receiver_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | NULL | jackID | NULL | amyID |
| 3 | NULL | JackID | amy | amyID |
| 6 | amy | amyID | jack | jackID |
| 7 | null | amyID | jack | jackID |

please help me

Comment: With that table it is imposible to know wich one is the latest. You need a column with a datetime/timestamp, or an autoincrement or something to stablish the order

Comment: I added the id column

Comment: If you are using MySql 8 the de-facto answer is to use a *row_number window partition*